# Javascript Executor in Page Object Model

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

For my automation script, written in Java with Selenium using Page Object Model, I would sometimes like to use Javascript Executor, because the default WebDriver clicks sometimes result in an exceptions of elements not being found.

In the framework's page, where the web elements are initialized, the code looks like this:

```
public class MainPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;


    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='main_button']/div/span")
    WebElement mainButton;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='login_button']/div/span")
    WebElement loginButton;

    // constructor, where the elements are initialized
    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //method, for clicking mainButton with WebDriver
    public void clickMainButton() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(mainButton)).click();
    }

    //method, for clicking mainButton with JS Executor
    public void clickLoginButton() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", loginButton);
    }
```

At this point, when executing the script interacting with the page, when calling the clickMainButton(); method, it's executed correctly. But when calling the clickLoginButton(); method, the program will throw a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pages.MainPage.clickLoginButton(MainPage.java:55)
```

If I create an instance of the Javascript Executor inside the clickLoginButton(); method, it works correctly.
My question is how to implement the Javascript Executor correctly with Page Object Model, without having to create a new instance of it in every method?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to the problem:

The correct way, to initialize the Javascript Executor in the class and in the constructor is:

```
public class MainPage {

WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait wait10;
private WebDriverWait wait40;
JavascriptExecutor executor;


@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='main_button']/div/span")
WebElement mainButton;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='login_button']/div/span")
WebElement loginButton;

// constructor, where the elements are initialized
public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.executor = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    this.wait10 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    this.wait40 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

//method, for clicking mainButton with WebDriver
public void clickMainButton() {
    wait40.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(mainButton)).click();
}

//method, for clicking mainButton with JS Executor
public void clickLoginButton() {
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", loginButton);
}
```

This could be applied for the WebDriverWait as well, with different explicit wait times (as it can be seen in the constructor).